# Tag score updated in one tag, but not others for same answer?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, caching, tag-score

On Meta Stack Overflow, I have a recent answer scoring 11 for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation)[review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits). The funny thing is that my tag score for [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) has updated to 11, but [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits) are still stuck at 5.

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is **not** that the tag scores haven't updated—I know that the tag scores are cached. The problem is that the tag score for [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) **has** updated, while the tag scores for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits) have **not**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, took me a bit to figure out what's going on (and it's funny it took so long, because I wrote the code that's doing the updating).

Normally, those tag stats on your profile are recalculated nightly, around 04:00 UTC.  However, because you started tracking the [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) badge in your user profile, we'll update that particular badge's counts much sooner, about once an hour.

As to why the other tags ([feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits)) are still at 5,  well, that was the answer score last night at 04:00 UTC.  [The answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336963/add-an-audit-to-documentation-that-asks-a-programming-question/336975#336975) picked up another 6 upvotes today.

The numbers should be reconciled after the job runs tonight, so check back after 04:00 UTC :)

Comment: I guess I should _probably_ edit the question to clarify. (Yes, I saw this before it was deleted.)

Comment: Nah, your question is fine - I completely forgot about the just-in-time updating of tracked tag badges, and the DB had some misleading info about the last time those values were updated (they were all showing 4:01 UTC).  I've checked in some code to properly update the last update timestamp and some comments, so hopefully it won't take me so long to figure it out!

Comment: @JD you actually missed me clarifying the question to another user in the comments.